# For loop in Each Row of Union

Tags: excel, vba, for-loop

```
Function Atotal(AB As Range, values As Range) As Double
    Atotal = 0  
    Items = Union(AB.Cells, values.Cells)

    For Each hrow In Items.Rows
       ' If AB cell.Value =="A" then
       ' Atotal = Atotal + values cell.Value
    Next hrow
End Function
```

For Example:

```
AB  |   VAL
------------
A   |   5
A   |   2
B   |   5
A   |   3
B   |   1
```

Atotal should be 10 (=5+2+3)

How to get this? How to loop through each row of Union and get the values of different range?

Comment: Isn't it easy to use excel functions `=SUMIF(A2:A6,"A",B2:B6)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need to use `Union` in this process.

```
Function Atotal(AB As Range, values As Range) As Double
    Atotal = 0

    Dim i As Integer
    For i = 1 To values.Rows.Count
        If AB.Cells(i, 1) = "A" Then
            Atotal = Atotal + values.Cells(i, 1).Value
        End If
    Next i

End Function
```